# Why Junit testing cannot see a directory that does exist causing me to not pass the test?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, intellij-plugin

I am working on a project on Jetbrains Academy, and I cannot pass the test due to this piece of code!

```
private static final String filesPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
            File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "server" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator;

if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(filesPath)) || !Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(filesPath))) {
        return CheckResult.wrong("Can't find '/server/data' folder");}
```

I have created this directory manually and still failed to pass the test ..
The test is being done online  through EduTools plugin from Jetbrains installed on my IDE .. But I have run the test class by myself, I did pass it successfully. But I don't know why the exact test running from the plugin fails!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. We do not see the JUnit test that fails. Also output the value of your `filesPath` field with a `System.out.println()` call to check what the JUnit test execution is actually seeing/using.

Comment: I actually can't do that. The test is being done online  through Edutools plugin from Jetbrains installed on my IDE .. But I have run the test class by myself, I did pass it successfully. But I don't know why the exact test running from the plugin fails!

Comment: Then use some other ways to save the result of the `filesPath` field when the unit test runs via the plugin. After that inspect the full path and how it is build together.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the value for `System.getProperty("user.dir")` because IDEA detect it as a your project root folder (not a home folder).
Simple test with [assertj](https://assertj.github.io/doc/)

```java
Assertions.assertThat(Paths.get(".", "data.txt"))
   .as("File 'data.txt' exists")
   .isRegularFile();
   // or .isDirectory() to check that your file is a directory
```

where your project might be

```sh
/home/users/XXX/projects/yyy/
  |- data.txt
  |- src/tests/java/.../SomeTest.java
```

and `System.getProperty("user.dir")` = `/home/users/XXX/projects/yyy`

Comment: user.dir is by definition the user's current working directory; under an IDE, it's entirely reasonable for it to be the project folder.  The home directory is held in the property user.home.